# Can a value be directly assigned to a pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am having trouble understanding the assignment to *string2* in the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void copy1( char * const s1, const char * const s2 ); /* prototype */
void copy2( char *s1, const char *s2 ); /* prototype */

int main( void )
{
    char string1[ 10 ]; /* create array string1 */
    char *string2 = "Hello"; /* create a pointer to a string */
    char string3[ 10 ]; /* create array string3 */
    char string4[] = "Good Bye"; /* create a pointer to a string */
```

I thought that pointers can be initialized only to NULL, 0, or address. Can you directly assign values to a char * data type?

Comment: Please copy/paste the code here

Comment: char *string2 = "Hello"

Comment: The code you are referencing in c language not c#.  The code has errors.  A c language character array must end with '\0'.  I don't know if the compiler is automatically adding the '\0' to the string.  Line 11 is creating a char array where string4 is the pointer (address where array starts).  string4 and string2 are equivalent methods of declaring an char array.

Comment: What is the purpose of these two functions copy1()/copy2(). Why do they *return* void?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a pointer variable can be assigned `NULL` (defined as 0), the address of a variable, or the value of another pointer. String literals are of type `char[]`, and plain array type can decay to a pointer, so you can assign a string literal to both `string2` and `string4`. It's the same as calling `print("Good Bye");` where you are passing a decayed `char*` to *printf*.

Comment: String literals indicate an array of type `char[]`, not `const char[]`, though it is undefined behavior to attempt to modify the contents of this array.

Comment: @DavidBowling Thanks, I have mistaken it with C++.

Comment: A couple more nitpicks-- `NULL` is the implementation-defined null pointer macro, but `(void *) 0` is guaranteed to be a null pointer. Also, one usually says that arrays _decay_ to pointers to their first elements, rather than degenerate.

Comment: @DavidBowling Thanks, forgot the common term.